# Powering a rechargeable battery with a solar cell

Tags: voltage, batteries, solar-cell

just a short question. I have a solar cell that outputs 7V. I want it to charge a 9V battery source. Is there anything I should be worried about or take note if I try to do this?

Comment: how can you charge a 9v battery by 7v ?

Comment: How do you have a rechargeable 9V battery?

Comment: You need a boost convertor.

Comment: You should be worried that it will not work. You should take note that it will not work. Vsolar MUST be >= Vbattery to charge the battery.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because the current will only flow towards the battery until it gets to 7 volts (actually will probably be slightly less than that).

If you still want to try it, I suggest you at least fit a diode in series because at least that way the current will only flow in one direction and the solar cell won't get damaged should the battery be at a higher voltage than the solar cell.